# how can i keep the gameobject only move in 90 degree withe another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

like this, how can I make the white one only move the 90-degree path with the red one.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is somewhat what you are searching for.

```
var radius = Vector3.Distance(redObject.transform.position, whiteObject.transform.position) ;
Vector3 direction = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0) * Vector3.right;
var newPosition = redObject.transform.position + direction * radius;
whiteObject.transform.position = newPosition;
```

Where you need to make your own direction and replace Vector.right with up or forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can set red as white parent (If it's acceptable in your scenario) when you rotate the red one the white one will rotate around the red one.